# Python-C API: Trouble packing C strings into a tuple

Tags: python, c, python-c-api

In the following code, I am trying to pack two null-terminated C strings (char pointers) into a Python tuple.

```
printf("word1 = '%s', word2 = '%s'\n", words1->wordArray[i], words2->wordArray[i]);
cmpArgs = Py_BuildValue("ss", words1->wordArray[i], words2->wordArray[i]);
printf("%s\n", PyString_AsString(PyTuple_GetItem(cmpArgs, 0)));
```

This produces output like:

```
word1 = '20', word2 = '20'
i┴
```

Why is the string different in the tuple than outside it? What am I doing wrong? Also, do I need to worry about incrementing and decrementing the reference count of this tuple? (I am creating it to pass to a Python function passed to C as a PyObject*)

Comment: Your code looks correct. Did you `#include <Python.h>`? Are you compiling with all the warnings turned on (`-Wall` with gcc)? Sometimes forgetting an `#include` can cause the generated code to incorrectly pass pointer arguments to variadic functions such as `Py_BuildValue`. Turning on warnings helps to catch that kind of bug (and many others).

Comment: Also, does it help if you replace `Py_BuildValue(...)` with `cmpArgs = PyTuple_New(2); PyTuple_SetItem(cmpArgs, 0, PyString_FromString(words1->wordArray[i]); PyTuple_SetItem(cmpArgs, 1, PyString_FromString(words2->wordArray[i]);`? If that helps, it points to `Py_BuildValue` being borked, likely due to a missing or broken header.

Comment: What headers could I need besides <Python.h>? (Which I am including) Trying your code messes up the strings horribly and causes it to go into an infinite loop. Could I be counting references incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got it--I was previously storing the words in a weird way using stack space. I started manually allocating space on the heap for them which seems to have fixed it.